# Batch media file concatenation

Tags: conversion, batch

Is there a command line tool for Windows 7 or Linux that given an m3u file, converts each file into one long file in a given format?

I have looked at avconv but it seems like it does not have this option. All files are wave audio file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to take a player that can output to stdout and then have `sox` read from stdin and convert appropriately.

```
mpg321 -s -@ playlist.m3u | sox -t raw -r 44.1k -e signed -b 16 -c 2 - output.mp3
```